# Short story about a vortex or wormwhole and something described as a broccoli cat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story that I read back in the 80s about a vortex or wormhole that has things coming through with one being described as something that looked like broccoli and a cat.  I believe the wormhole turned out to be a kind of garbage chute,  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Since you are new have a look at our [tour] and [help]. Specifically I would suggest looking at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11788/magic-link-for-how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). Add in as many details as you can to give our experts the best chance at finding what you are looking for!

Answer (score 21):

This is most likely "[Litterbug](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53507)" (1969) by Tony Morphett, first published in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, July 1969 and collected several times after.  (Interestingly, this is the only listed SF work by Morphett.)

The protagonist is an inventor who has started selling "garbage disposals" that are really single-ended matter transmission units.  He has no idea where the other ends are, but they're not on Earth.

> Rafferty went to the machine. The power was still on. The grey vortex in the transmission area was as it should have been. Rafferty had a peach left over from his breakfast. He put it on the conveyor belt. The conveyor belt bore the peach into **the grey vortex**, where it disappeared. Rafferty waited.

Then weird stuff starts coming back:

> He picked it up. It **resembled a cat and it resembled a four-legged bunch of broccoli**, and it wasn't either. It was dead, and among the things it didn't resemble was a bunch of violets.

@FuzzyBoots points out that you can read the original story (in *MF&SF*) at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v037n01_1969-07_PDF/page/n109/mode/2up).  (It's also available in [*The Best from Fantasy and Science Fiction: Nineteenth Series*](https://archive.org/details/bestfromfantas00ferm/page/223/mode/1up), but you need to register to borrow it.)

Comment: Och! Just beat me to it. :-D

Comment: FWIW, that issue is available at https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v037n01_1969-07_PDF/page/n109/mode/2up